# Select All in GridView is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a .net Gridview in which "Select All" checkbox has been added to select all the rows available in grid. Below is my Grid code

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
  <HeaderTemplate>
  <input id="chkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAllDataGridCheckBoxes('chkItem',this.checked)">
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItem" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckAllDataGridCheckBoxes(aspCheckBoxID, checkVal)
    {
        re = new RegExp(':' + aspCheckBoxID + '$')  //generated control name starts with a colon
        for(i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++)
        {
            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]
            if (elm.type == 'checkbox')
            {
                if (re.test(elm.name))
                    elm.checked = checkVal
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

why my all rows remains unselected when i click "Select All". What's wrong here in my javascript?

Updated Javascript

```
 function CheckAllDataGridCheckBoxes(aspCheckBoxID, checkVal)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++)
        {
            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i]
            if (elm.name.endsWith(aspCheckBoxID))
            {
                    elm.checked = checkVal
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: change Form1 to document.forms[0]?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I am able to get into loop now but still, my "Select All Rows" functionality is not working..What's more missing here? Thanks

Comment: give an example of out of the client ids of the checkbox...you can do that via the "view source" option after the page has loaded...that will tell you if your regex is valid

Comment: `IMT_cpDefaultContentPlaceHolder_dgRegions_ctl02_chkItem` is the id of the checkbox of the row from "View Source". Does regex is valid?

Comment: I think my regex is invalid..Could you please guide me to format the right ones as per the id's generated..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not necessary to do this task.  Use this instead:

```
if (elm.name.endsWith(aspCheckBoxID))
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: I have updated my post with new Javascript as per your suggestion, still its not working.What's wrong in new script?

Comment: Instead of `aspCheckBoxID` value coming is '__VIEWSTATE'

Comment: That's your first input var...you are selecting all of them on the form...but you only want ones endimg with that string